# primeng p-menubar routerLink not navigating to the component

Tags: routes, angular7, primeng

I am using primeng p-menubar on my code.I have used routerLink to navigate to the page but the routerLink is not working. When I click on the menubar tab the url changes but the page doesn't route there. My code is private 
items: MenuItem[];

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [{
            label: "SBH Vendor Funding",
            routerLink: ['/coops/vendor-funding']
        }, {
            label: "Vendor Contact List",
            routerLink: "."
        }, {
            label: "Co-Op Sales Actuals",
            url: this.COOPACTUALSURL,
            target:"_blank"
        },  {
            label: "Manage Users",
            routerLink: ['/users/manage users']
            }]
  }
```

The URL is being changed but is not navigated to the component it is supposed to.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: you really need to share your route model .. but i think you are missing comma in your route path routerLink: ['./coops/vendor-funding']

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'coops', loadChildren: './coops/coops.module#CoopsModule' },
    { path: 'coopform', loadChildren: './coopForm/coopform.module#CoopformModule' },
    { path: 'users', loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule' },
]

Comment: where is the vendor-funding route in your routes ?  I still dont see all page routes has been added properly

Comment: It is inside Coop Module Routing.     const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: CoopContainerComponent },
    { path: 'vendor-funding', component: CoopContainerComponent }]